# Vim execute in function behaving differently

Tags: function, vim, highlight

I am playing around with a small Vim function that will highlight whitespace.

But the `execute` command is behaving differently than when its called directly.

So the function looks like this:

```
function! ShowWhitespace()
    execute "/\\s\\+$"
endfunction
```

And it is mapped as:

```
command! SW call ShowWhitespace()
```

When `:SW` is executed it simply searches and gets the cursor to where whitespace exists.

*However*, when I do this in the command line:

```
:exe "/\\s\\+$"
```

It highlights correctly the whitespace. I am also making sure that `highlightsearch` is always on, so this is not an issue of having it on or off.

As a side note, I need to have this in a function because I want to have other things that have not yet been added to it for flexibility (like toggling for example).

Why would this behave differently in a function than executing it directly? I've written a wealth of functions in Vim and never seen this work different.

EDIT & Solution:

So it seems Vim doesn't like having functions altering searches. As soon as a function exits the search patterns are cleared (as pointed out by `:help function-search-undo`.

This might look ugly but does what I was looking to do in the first place:

```
command! -bang Ws let orig_line = line('.') | exe ((<bang>0)?":set hls!":":set hls") | exe '/\s\+$' |  exe orig_line
```

Explained bit by bit:

- Maps the (bang-accepting) `Ws` command to the following actions:
- saves the original line where cursor is located
- depending on bang or no bang (e.g. `:Ws!` or `:Ws`) it sets `highlightsearch`
- Executes the search to find whitespace
- Goes back to the original line if it changed

Answer (score 2):

If you don't wish to move the cursor (and never do it), just set `@/` to the correct search pattern, i.e.:

```
let @/ = '\s\+$'
```

NB: the function should have moved the cursor.

Comment: it is not about the cursor, it is about the behavior. Why is it different? How can I achieve the result I want? (highlighting whitespace from a function)

Comment: By setting directly the variable used by highlightsearch -> `@/`. Regarding the explanation of your misbehaviour, see `:h function-search-undo`

Comment: Tried this and still doesn't highlight anything.

Comment: That's odd, this works perfectly with my gvim7.3-3 on windows -- assuming `&hlsearch` is set. BTW, you really don't need to use `/` ; setting `@/` is more than enough, and the best way to proceed as it doesn't move the cursor at all.

Comment: Are you executing that inside a function? or globally? Inside of a function (as per my question) didn't work for me.

Comment: I have used it from within a function (but hlsearch was set before calling the function). Otherwise, when outside it will still work (and this way you won't have to move the cursor at the **beginning** of the line from where you execute your mapping)